# Architectural decision : QT or Eclipse Platform?

Tags: qt, architecture, eclipse-plugin

We are in the process of designing a tool to be used with HDEM(High Definition Electron Microscope).We get stacks of 2D images from HDEM and first step is 'detecting borders' on the sections.After detecting edges of 2D slices ,next step is construct the 3D model using these 2D slices.

This 'border detecting' algorithm(s)  is/are implemented by one of professor and he has used and suggests to use C.(to gain high performance and probably will parallelise  in future)
We have to develop comprehensive UI ,3D viewer ,2D editor...etc and use this algorithm.

Application should support usual features like project save/open.Undo,Redo...etc

Our technology decisions are:

> A) Build entire platform from the
>   scratch using QT.
>
> B) Use Eclipse Platform

Our concerns are,

if we choose A) we can easily integrate the 'border detecting' algorithm(s) because the development environment is C/C++ But we have to implement the basic features from the scratch.

If we choose B) we get basic features from the Eclipse platform , but integrating C libraries going to be a tedious task.

Any suggestions on this?

Comment: Have you looked at VTK? (http://www.vtk.org/)

Comment: We cannot use VTK, because we use entirely new algorithms and application should be user friendly,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd go for Qt any time:-)

If you need a IDE framework to build your project on you might want to consider Qt together with Qt creator. The latter is a really nice IDE to develop with and can be extended with custom plugins, pretty much like eclipse.

Comment: +1 on Qt, though I've found it's much easier to work with Eclipse CDT and Qt Integration on complex projects.

Comment: Yes, Eclipse is a great IDE from all I heard about it. I did try to use eclipse occasionaly, but always got put off by it: It was just to overwhelming and I could never find any good introduction focusing on C/C++ development in it. Any tips here? ;-) The Eclipse for Java development intros were pretty good though, unfortunately they never transfered well to CDT.

I did find Qt Creator really simple to get into and am sticking with it nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

If you need performance and a well-controlled process I'd suggest going the Qt way.

Qt has a well documented class library that should make implementation of basic features fairly easy and intuitive. It also has OpenGL support for 3D and good 2D editing capabilities.

I've recently built a monitoring application with a custom UI and it was fairly easy once you get past the basic concepts behind the framework.